# How to implement auto-answer on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-privateapi

Apparently, there are already some applications implementing auto-answer on iphone:

http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=20776

How is this done? How can I automatically answer calls programmatically? (private APIs ok)

Comment: "You can purchase AutoAnswer from the Cydia Store for $1.99", this can only occur on jailbroken devices, it's not functionality that Apple provide publicly. Is this OK?

Comment: Yes. I am having that in account. I would like to implement this usign private apis.

Answer (score 1):

First, one note on jailbroken vs private API:

Private API are just undocumented API, which can be executed on jailed or jailbroken devices. However, Apple will reject (won't accept them to AppStore) apps with private API usage. So, you can use them on jailed device, but you will have problem with distribution of this app.

My guess is that AutoAnswer is jailbreak tweak. They can be executed only on jailbroken phones.

I think the easiest way to learn how AutoAnswer is implemented would be to disassemble it and check which API it hooks. The harder way would be to disassemble Phone application (may be it's part of Springboard, I don't remember) and find which API you need to hook to provide the same functionality.